# Vector Calculus Identity Help Needed

Tags: vector-analysis

Ive been given a question:
Prove that if $f$ is a (smooth) scalar field and $\overrightarrow {G}$ is an irrotational vector field, then $$(∇f × \overrightarrow {G} )f$$ is solenoidal

Ive got the identities in front of me but i dont know how to apply them to this question.

I know I have to use the identity $$∇·(fG)= (∇f)·G+ f∇·G$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\nabla f\times G$ is a vector field, $f$ is a scalar field. Can you start by applying the identity for the divergence of the product of a scalar field and a vector field?

Comment: Could I use the identity  ∇ (fG ) = (∇~f) · G+ f∇ · G as its in the same format as the question I asked? @Rahul

Comment: Maybe? I don't know, your identity is hard to read.

Comment: $$∇ (fG ) = (∇f) · G+ f∇ · G$$ is that easier to read?? @Rahul

Comment: Yes, assuming the left-hand side is meant to be $\nabla\cdot(fG)$ instead, that looks right. Go ahead and do that (though instead of $f$ and $G$ you have $f$ and $\nabla f\times G$ of course).

Comment: see ive used this identity and got $$(∇f×G)f= (f∇f)⋅G+(f∇f)⋅G$$. I dont know where to go from here. @Rahul

Comment: I don't know how you got that, you must have made an algebraic error somewhere. Add your derivation to the question and maybe someone else will point out where you went wrong. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\nabla\cdot\bracks{\pars{\nabla f \times \vec{G}}f}
\\[5mm] = &
\overbrace{\nabla f\cdot \pars{\nabla f \times \vec{G}}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
f\,\nabla\cdot\pars{\nabla f \times \vec{G}} =
f\bracks{\vec{G}\cdot\underbrace{\pars{\nabla\times\nabla f}}_{\ds{=\ \vec{0}}} - \nabla f \cdot \underbrace{\pars{\nabla \times G}}_{\ds{=\ \vec{0}}}} =
\color{#f00}{0}
\end{align}